# Rcpp: Apply lfactorial to NumericVector

Tags: r, rcpp

What is the nicest/easiest way to apply the `lfactorial` function to a `NumericVector` in Rcpp. In R I would have something like this:

```
> vec <- c(1,2,3,4)
> lfactorial(vec)
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.7917595 3.1780538
```

In Rcpp, suppose I have:

```
NumericVector vec = NumericVector::create(1,2,3,4);
```

What is the nicest way to apply `Rcpp::internal::lfactorial` to each element of `vec`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rcpp, just like R, is vectorized:

```
R> cppFunction('NumericVector lfac(NumericVector x) { \
                                        return lfactorial(x); }')
R> lfac(1:4)
[1] 0.000000 0.693147 1.791759 3.178054
R>
```

That is one line of code I simply broke for nicer exposition here. Remove the backslash before copying and pasting.  You can write it either as a `NumericVector` or `IntegerVector` signature.

Comment: do you think an R package written in Rcpp has a higher chance of being accepted by CRAN?

Comment: I don't think that it plays a role.  Your package needs to be free of warnings, errors and note when `R CMD check` runs, and ideally be correct too.  *I* find it easier to use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) and so seem to do a lot of other people -- but [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries) just today showed another package containing C++ but not using [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html).  It even used `.C()` is is in fact discouraged....

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I am developing the package in Rstudio so it is helping me catch the warnings and errors in advance. Is that the main reason that packages are often rejected?